# How to fix Heroku CLI installer error "This app has been blocked for your protection" on Windows 10?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am on an admin account and have downloaded the Heroku CLI installer from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli).

Whenever I try to install it, Windows gives me a message:

"This app has been blocked for your protection"

and shows me that the Publisher is Unknown.

Has anyone else had the same problems? What was the fix? I'm sure the installer from the official site is legit but you can never be too safe.

EDIT 4/28/2021:

I put in a ticket with Heroku and the problem has been fixed as of April 27, 2021. The Windows binary has been updated and new instructions are listed at

[Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)

EDIT:

To clarify, Windows does not give me a "More Info" option. The only thing I can do is click "Close".

Answer (score 17):

**Easiest steps I've found to work around this issue:**

1. Open CMD as administrator
2. Open folder location of the installer; e.g. `cd c:\users\user\downloads\`
3. Type `heroku-x64.exe` or `heroku-x86.exe` for 64-bit or 32-bit respectively
4. Voilà! The installer application should launch and bypass the UAC prompt

*[Other information that might be useful](https://www.minitool.com/news/an-administrator-has-blocked-you-from-running-this-app.html)*

Comment: @Levi Wilkerson Your answer was a great work around but the real "fix" occurred when I put in a ticket with Heroku and they fixed the Windows binary. The error no longer appears.

Comment: I didn't take the time to report the bug, I figured they were aware of it - thanks for taking the time! I'm sure they appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

open window PowerShell as administrator paste this
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force

restart your pc
run the program hopefully it works

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows 10 and have the same error like you for Windows installer. I have tried all the suggested work-around in here but ended up using NPM to install the Heroku-CLI.

`npm install -g heroku`

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#npm

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened at me and it is saying this app has been blocked for your protection I think there must be problem connected with updated version of current heroku cli hope they will fix it soon and they have reported solution for this bug at here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the problem. You may try the official steps.

Currently, the Windows installers may display a warning titled “Windows protected your PC”. To run the installation when this warning is shown, click “More info”, verify the publisher as “Heroku, Inc.”, then click the “Run anyway” button.

Comment: The warning message appear to me with no "More info" option. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

definetly there's is an issue i tried everything i could. Lastly I came up with the solution

I installed it using Node.js (npm)

npm install -g heroku

And worked for me.

Comment: This does not directly address the original question.

Comment: there's something wrong with windows cli installer....I tried on different windows machine. the orignal question should be answered by the developers of heroku. I just answered what helped me to achieve the target which i would have achieved using heroku cli for windows installer

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install right now which is mentioned on heroku's website

**

> npm install -g heroku

**

source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#npm

Answer (score 0):

I put in a ticket with Heroku and the problem has been fixed as of April 27, 2021. The Windows binary has been updated and new instructions are listed at

[Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install)